# impossible to install Driver on Windows 10

Tags: windows, drivers

I trying to know if it is possible to force installation of a driver on windows? I am using Linux all the time and I am a little bit lost on widows. This is the situation:

I used a Lenovo Yoga Pro2 with wiht Intel(R) HD Graphic Family adpter (i5-4200U) I used it since 2014 with fedora installed on it. I could use Vulkan with not problem. I just got a new laptop so a decide to use the old one to compile my code on Windows just to have a Win version.

I code didn't work I got

```
VkResult = VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER = -4294967287,
```

And whenI try vkcude demo,

```
I got do you have a compatible vulkan installable client driver (icd) installed
```

so I decided to update the driver, the intel driver failed to install telling me

```
The driver being installed is not validated for this computer. Please obtain the appropriate driver form the manufacturer.
```

I got the driver from Lenovo but looks like it is not build with vulkan compatibility in it.

My question is: Is it possible to force the intel driver to install anyways or is there any solutions?

EDIT: I found intel solution for this specific problem And I've been able to install the last driver unfortunaly looks like it doesn't support vulkan. I am supprised to see that I can't found a driver that support vulkan on windowns for the same hardware that works on linux.

Comment: You do know that Vulcan still requires hardware support even if you have a driver that normally would support it.  Your Intel GPU is simply old and barely supported on the current version of Windows 10

Comment: I Don't know windows, honestly, but Vulkan works with the same hardware on Fedora 30/31/32/33 and debian 10 I tested it on those. so I certifie that is not hardware problem, nor a Vulkan problem but clearly windows and/or driver for windows. SO I guess you are telling me that If I want to keep using this machine I will have to go back to linux?

Comment: I am saying that Intel stopped updating their drivers for your hardware over a year ago, that version that is released is not the current driver model that they used for their newer hardware.  If you want a more specific answer you will have to provide information about which driver you installed. Lenovo doesn't always have the most drivers on their website.

Comment: 2/5/2021 driver file : win64_15.40.5171.exe, From Device Manager: driver version: 20.19.15.5171. Driver date: 11/4/2020